# mysql - group, but show all row of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, concatenation

I want to group fields but want to show all row of a column called `remain`:

**here is current output without grouping:**

[image]

**And output with group:**

[image]

**And I want This when I group:**

[image]

**Here is mysql query:**

```
SELECT staff.name,
  staff.designation_id_designation,
  staff.status_id_status,
  Concat_Ws('=', leave_remain.leave_type_id_leave_type, leave_remain.days) AS
  remain
FROM staff INNER JOIN
  leave_remain ON staff.id_staff = leave_remain.staff_id_staff
GROUP BY staff.name
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT  staff.name,
        staff.designation_id_designation,
        staff.status_id_status,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Concat_Ws('=', leave_remain.leave_type_id_leave_type, leave_remain.days)) AS remain
FROM    staff 
        INNER JOIN leave_remain 
            ON staff.id_staff = leave_remain.staff_id_staff
GROUP   BY staff.name, staff.designation_id_designation, staff.status_id_status
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/729f7/1)

other Link(s)

- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: convert all numbers into string, `Concat_Ws('=', CAST(leave_remain.leave_type_id_leave_type AS VARCHAR(30)), CAST(leave_remain.days AS VARCHAR(30)))`

Comment: what version of mysql you are using?

Comment: oh it's a syntax error, it should be `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/729f7/7

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT staff.name,
  staff.designation_id_designation,
  staff.status_id_status,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Concat_Ws('=', leave_remain.leave_type_id_leave_type, leave_remain.days) SEPARATOR ' ') AS remain
FROM staff INNER JOIN
  leave_remain ON staff.id_staff = leave_remain.staff_id_staff
GROUP BY staff.designation_id_designation,
         staff.name,
         staff.status_id_status;
```

Answer (score 1):

TRy this for this we need to use group_contact seperate by ' '.

```
SELECT staff.name,
  staff.designation_id_designation,
  staff.status_id_status,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Concat_Ws('=', leave_remain.leave_type_id_leave_type, leave_remain.days) SEPARATOR ' ') AS remain
FROM staff 
INNER JOIN
  leave_remain 
ON 
staff.id_staff = leave_remain.staff_id_staff
GROUP BY staff.designation_id_designation,
         staff.name,
         staff.status_id_status;
```