# How to return an array of hashes grouped by a certain column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Placements model that shows employees and their end of month position on a log:

```
[<Placement id: 1, employee_name: 'John', month: "2014-02-01",position: 2>, 
<Placement id: 2, employee_name: 'John', month: "2014-01-01", position: 2>, 
<Placement id: 3, employee_name: 'Jill', month: "2014-02-01", position: 3>,
<Placement id: 4, employee_name: 'Jill', month: "2014-01-01", position: 1>
<Placement id: 5, employee_name: 'Fred', month: "2014-02-01", position: 1>]
```

How would I return an array of hashes like the one below:

```
[
{ month: '2014-02-01', 'John': 2, 'Jill': 3, 'Fred': 1 },
{ month: '2014-01-01', 'John': 2, 'Jill': 1 }
]
```

Comment: to return this type of value you can use `jbulder`

Comment: these are not valid hashes.

Comment: @thorstenmüller But I bet you understand what the OP is asking for.

Comment: your_array.as_json will work

Comment: @NitinJ No, because the hash is different than the array.

Comment: i do that Model.all.as_json and that's work . yeah i understand that array and hash are different . will keep that in mind

Comment: This is a good question and appears frequently in real life problems. (I wouldn't return the hash as you do though but still, good question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [ <Placement id: 1, employee_name: 'John', month: "2014-02-01",position: 2>, 
      <Placement id: 2, employee_name: 'John', month: "2014-01-01", position: 2>, 
      <Placement id: 3, employee_name: 'Jill', month: "2014-02-01", position: 3>,
      <Placement id: 4, employee_name: 'Jill', month: "2014-01-01", position: 1>
      <Placement id: 5, employee_name: 'Fred', month: "2014-02-01", position: 1> ]

a.group_by(&:month).map  do |month, data|
  hash = {month: month}
  data.each {|placement| hash[placement.employee_name] = placement.position}
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do database grouping instead of grouping in the code as it's more efficient.

If you're using `mysql`, you could do the following:

(credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806663/226255 )

```
r = Placement.connection.select_all(
 "select date_format(month, '%Y-%m') as monthy,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Concat_Ws('=', employee_name, position)) AS place 
  from placements 
  group by year(month), month(month)")

=> [{"monthy"=>"2014-01", "placement"=>"John=2,Jill=1"},
 {"monthy"=>"2014-02", "placement"=>"John=2,Jill=3,Fred=1"}]
```

Check the sqlfiddle here:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/088e7/1/0

Now, in the code, convert to a hash that is similar to that in your question:

```
r.map { |m| 
  h = { :month => m["monthy"] }
  m["placement"].split(',').each { |i| 
  k, v = i.split('='); h[k] = v.to_i }; h 
}

=> [{:month=>"2014-01", "John"=>2, "Jill"=>1},
{:month=>"2014-02", "John"=>2, "Jill"=>3, "Fred"=>1}]
```

Comment: @jumpingcode why not? I just tried it and it does collect all the attributes for the active record objects

Comment: Yup.. The OP said he has a `Placement` model so it does `respond_to?` `:attributes`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activemodel serializers [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Eg from doc

```
user = User.find(1)
user.as_json
# => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#     "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true}

ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true

user.as_json
# => { "user" => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#                  "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true } }
```

Comment: These are not the values you're looking for.

Comment: yeah, this is a example.  I think his Hash is also wrong

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 placements = [<Placement id: 1, employee_name: 'John', month: "2014-02-01",position: 2>, 
    <Placement id: 2, employee_name: 'John', month: "2014-01-01", position: 2>, 
    <Placement id: 3, employee_name: 'Jill', month: "2014-02-01", position: 3>,
    <Placement id: 4, employee_name: 'Jill', month: "2014-01-01", position: 1>
    <Placement id: 5, employee_name: 'Fred', month: "2014-02-01", position: 1>]

    placements.map!{|placement| placement.attributes}
```

Comment: I had a similar answer: `placements.map(&:attributes)` ; it looks like the OP, however, is asking about grouping.